# Why can't I parse this CSV file inside of node.js?

Tags: node.js, csv

Here's my code:

```
var options = {

    rowDelimiter: 'windows',
    encoding: 'ascii'

}

var data = fs.readFileSync(localFolder+'/'+file, 'ascii');                  

console.log(data);

csv().from.string(data, options).to.array(function(data, count) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

The first `console.log` returns the following data:

`"Filename","DID#","Document Type","Date Sent","School","First Name","Middle Name","Last Name","DOB","SSN","Application #","Common App ID","RH CEEB","Class Of","Years Attended"
"TR58A3D.pdf","TR58A3D","Transcript","07/19/2012","zz Screaming Eagle High School","Kim","","Smith","05/05/1995","","","","555555","2013",""
"TR58AQH.pdf","TR58AQH","Transcript","07/19/2012","zz Screaming Eagle High School","Jon","","Sink","05/09/1996","","","","555555","2015",""`

`[scott@localhost]$ file transcripts/index_07_19_2012_1043460.csv
transcripts/index_07_19_2012_1043460.csv: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

The second `console.log` doesn't print anything to my console. Anyone have any ideas why it's not parsing the CSV?

Comment: `.from.path` expects a file path, not a string of data, but I don't know how to pass options using just `.from(data)`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried from.string(), and that doesn't appear to be working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the value for `rowDelimiter` option. It needs to be the actual line break character used - i.e.: `\r\n` or `\r`.